# How to emit message from node server to angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest

I'm stuck on one problem with my app.
Player is connecting to the game. Nextly, he chooses a remote player and then angularjs is sending by restapi to nodejs informations about this player and checking for any awaiting games. If there is no game currently awaiting - player waits for another player. If he comes, there is this same situation but node is returning an object with game to new player, but how to emit/broadcast any information to wake'up first player, who's waiting?

I tried with angular promise, but don't have any idea how to trigger any data from node to angular promise when another player will connect...

Here's my app.js

```js
mySessionData.$promise.then(function(sessionData){
       
rpsManager.setMySessionId(sessionData.sessionID);
var gamePlay = $resource("/game/nick/:nick/item/:item/sessionid/:sessionid", {nick: '@nick', item: '@item', sessionid: '@sessionid'});
var gameData = gamePlay.save({
  nick: rpsManager.getPlayerNick(), 
  item: rpsManager.getPlayerItem(), 
  sessionid: rpsManager.getMySessionId()
 });

gameData.$promise.then(
 function (result) {
  
  if (result.gameId != undefined && result.nick != undefined && result.item != undefined) {
   
   rpsManager.setPlayerEnemyData({gameId: result.gameId, nick: result.nick, item: result.item});
   console.log('result: ', result);
   TweenMax.to($('.rps_select_player'), 0.8, {css: {transform: "translateY(-100vh)"}, ease:Power2.easeOut, onComplete: function(){
    scope.$emit('stateChange', 5);
   }}).delay(2);
  }
 }, 
 function (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }, 
 function (progress) {
  console.log(progress);
 });
});
```

here's my node js:

```js
app.all('/game/getsession', function(req, res){
 var sessionID = req.sessionID;
 res.send({sessionID: sessionID});
});

app.all('/game/nick/:nick/item/:item/sessionid/:sessionid', function (req, res) {
 var sessionID = req.params.sessionid;
 var gameToPlay = _checkForWaitingGames(sessionID, req, gamesAwaiting);
 
 if (gameToPlay) {
  res.send(gameToPlay);
 } else {
  console.log(gameToPlay);
  console.log('Currently no games... waiting for players');
 }
 
});
```

Comment: Have a look at web sockets, eg the socket.io module.

Comment: Web sockets are what you need. I've been using this library which works great: https://github.com/websockets/ws